# capture stdout of subprocess.Popen when there is exception raised

Tags: python, exception, subprocess

How to capture the stdout/stderr from subprocess.Popen CMD call when there is exception raised?

code snippet:

```
p_cmd = subprocess.Popen(CMD, bufsize=0, shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(cmd_stdo, cmd_stde) = p_cmd.communicate(timeout=60)
```

If the CMD is `timeout` which run over `60 secs`, how could I get the CMD stdout output in `cmd_stdo` or `cmd_stde`?

I try to get it in `try, exception` block it's NULL.
And, I am pretty sure that there is OUTPUT when running CMD.

Answer (score 3):

In case of time-out, the variables `cmd_stdo` and `cmd_stde` are never assigned to, because the exception happens before the assignment.

To make sure `stdout` and `stderr` are captured even in case of the exception, I'd capture to (temporary) files and read them into variables afterwards.

```
import subprocess
from tempfile import TemporaryFile as Tmp

CMD = [ 'echo "before sleep" ; sleep 7 ; echo "after sleep"' ]

with Tmp() as out, Tmp() as err:
    p_cmd = subprocess.Popen(CMD, bufsize=0, shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=out, stderr=err)
    timed_out = False
    try:
        p_cmd.wait(timeout=5)
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        timed_out = True
    out.seek(0)
    err.seek(0)
    str_out = out.read()
    str_err = err.read()

print('Has timed out:', timed_out)
print('Stdout:', str_out)
print('Stderr:', str_err)
```

(When trying this out, play with sleep and timeout times in the code to make time-out happen or not)

Comment: Thanks for your support. SO if they (err, out) are files, they would be updated gradually? If they are vars, they would be assigned when there is exception.

Comment: Files are "update gradually", yes, but dependent on buffering. When using variables, the actual assignment to the vars never actually happens even when in inside `try..except`. Just try it top see.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have enough reputation I have to ask for clarification this way.

Are you trying to run it on Windows or Linux?